# Getting multiple messages in response in slack Event API

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I have created a slackbot using slackclient and python. It runs perfectly fine. However, after a certain period of time, I start getting multiple messages from the bot.

```
    if self.messages.get(team_id):
        self.messages[team_id].update({user_id: message.Message()})
    else:
        self.messages[team_id] = {user_id: message.Message()}
    message_obj = self.messages[team_id][user_id]
    message_obj.channel = self.open_dm(user_id)

    message_obj.create_attachments()
    post_message = self.client.api_call("chat.postMessage",
                                        channel=message_obj.channel,
                                        username=self.name,
                                        icon_emoji=self.emoji,
                                        text=message_obj.text,
                                        attachments=message_obj.attachments
                                        )
```

Comment: Please add the relevant part of your code if you want people to help you

Comment: Thanks for suggestion and I added @ErikKalkoken

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Slack Events API: Events are posted (multiple times) for responses of own bot user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59489908/slack-events-api-events-are-posted-multiple-times-for-responses-of-own-bot-us)