# Slack Events API: Events are posted (multiple times) for responses of own bot user

Tags: django, events, bots, slack, slack-api

I seem to have a problem when responding to incoming messages via the Slack Events API ([im.message event](https://api.slack.com/events/message.im)).

- When a user (in this case `UQ364CBPF`) sends a message to my App Home, the events API correctly posts an event to my backend (=first line in the logs below).
- I respond to the event with an HTTP 200 OK, and in my code (see below), I trigger a response from my Bot User.
- This response is sent correctly in Slack.

**But**: after that, the events API keeps posting events that *my own bot user* has posted a message in this channel...

Also, where the events are usually posted only 3 times, these events just keep being posted non-stop. Even though the bot user only sent one response message in Slack.

```
User UQ364CBPF has posted message: I'm typing a message to my Slack bot. in DQ5FF35N2 of channel type: im
[26/Dec/2019 15:16:30] "POST /slack/events/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
User UQ5529KTR has posted message: Thank you for your message! We will get back to you soon! in DQ5FF35N2 of channel type: im
[26/Dec/2019 15:16:32] "POST /slack/events/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
User UQ5529KTR has posted message: Thank you for your message! We will get back to you soon! in DQ3KX0NPJ of channel type: im
[26/Dec/2019 15:16:33] "POST /slack/events/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
User UQ5529KTR has posted message: Thank you for your message! We will get back to you soon! in DQ3KX0NPJ of channel type: im
[26/Dec/2019 15:16:35] "POST /slack/events/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
User UQ5529KTR has posted message: Thank you for your message! We will get back to you soon! in DQ3KX0NPJ of channel type: im
[26/Dec/2019 15:16:37] "POST /slack/events/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
User UQ5529KTR has posted message: Thank you for your message! We will get back to you soon! in DQ3KX0NPJ of channel type: im
[26/Dec/2019 15:16:39] "POST /slack/events/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
User UQ5529KTR has posted message: Thank you for your message! We will get back to you soon! in DQ3KX0NPJ of channel type: im
[26/Dec/2019 15:16:40] "POST /slack/events/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
User UQ5529KTR has posted message: Thank you for your message! We will get back to you soon! in DQ3KX0NPJ of channel type: im
[26/Dec/2019 15:16:42] "POST /slack/events/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
User UQ5529KTR has posted message: Thank you for your message! We will get back to you soon! in DQ3KX0NPJ of channel type: im
[26/Dec/2019 15:16:43] "POST /slack/events/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
User UQ5529KTR has posted message: Thank you for your message! We will get back to you soon! in DQ3KX0NPJ of channel type: im
```

In my code, this is part of a bigger function that processes Slack events, the relevant part:

```
@csrf_exempt
def slack_events(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        json_data = json.loads(request.body)
        event_callback_type = json_data['event']['type']
        if event_callback_type == 'message':
                user_id = json_data['event']['user']
                text = json_data['event']['text']
                channel_id = json_data['event']['channel']
                channel_type = json_data['event']['channel_type']
                timestamp = json_data['event']['ts']
                print ('User ' + user_id + ' has posted message: ' + text + ' in ' + channel_id + ' of channel type: ' + channel_type)
                slack_message_received(user_id, channel_id, channel_type, team_id, timestamp, text)
                return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

There is nothing in here (or in the function `slack_message_received`) could trigger this recurring flow.

So

**1. Is it strange behavior that Slack is bombarding me with all these
       POST requests from my own bot user?**

**2. Can I avoid this behavior, other than filtering out my own Bot User ID and ignoring these requests on backend side?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's standard behavior of the Events API that your bot will receive all message events, including from it's own posts. And by reacting to them you have created and endless loop.

To address this issue you need to stop reacting to the bot's own messages by filtering them out as you suggested in #2. That is the standard approach.

The easiest is to just filter out all bot messages, if you don't need to listen to other bots. Then you can just ignore all messages that have the `subtype` property. Alternatively you can of course filter our messages from your own bot.

Comment: Thank you for this answer!  Indeed I forgot that this would trigger an infinite loop of response - response - ...

Comment: @GillesVanermen Can you please share the code or link of how you did that, I am having issues writing the code to find the BotID.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. But when I printed the request, I couldn't find `subtype` so the solution above didn't work for me.
[log detail showing what is in the request I receive. There was no `subtype`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikB6E.jpg)

Instead, I noticed that messages from bot had `bot_id` and messages from users didn't.
Therefore, my solution was like this:

```py
    @slack_events_adapter.on("message")
    def say_hello(event_data):
       print('EVENT_DATA')
       print(event_data)
       message = event_data['event']

       # if the incoming message contains "hello" NOT CASE SENSITIVE, then respond with a designed message
       # "subtype" doesnt help to filter bot's message event and user's message event
       if message.get('bot_id') is None and 'hello' in ((message.get('text')).lower()):
           channel_id = message['channel']
           user = message['user']
           message = "Hello <@%s>! :tada:" % user
           slack_web_client.chat_postMessage(channel=channel_id, text=message)
       else:
           return
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Phoebe said - while retrieving the events using

```
slack_message.get('event')
```

I didn't find a key as `bot_id`. I think this is an issue from Slack Events api.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30434556)