# Slackbot chat.postMessage posting messages nonstop

Tags: java, chatbot, resttemplate, slack, slack-api

I have created a slack bot that interacts with my java application. Whenever the bot receives a message in private chat or as an app_mention, I want it to reply to that message. I have written the following service to receive a message:

```
        ObjectNode objectNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(eventDto.getChallenge())) {
            objectNode.put("challenge", eventDto.getChallenge());
        } else if (eventDto.getEvent().has("type")
                && "message".equalsIgnoreCase(eventDto.getEvent().get("type").asText())) {
            objectNode.put("text", "Bot called in a private chat.");
            objectNode.put("channel", eventDto.getEvent().get("channel").asText());
            slackWebApiService.postMessageInChat(botAuthToken, objectNode);
        } else {
            objectNode.put("text", "Bot is called in a channel");
            objectNode.put("channel", eventDto.getEvent().get("channel").asText());
            slackWebApiService.postMessageInChat(botAuthToken, objectNode);
        }
        return objectNode;
    }
```

SlackWebApiService.postMessageInChat is as follows:

```
        requestHeader.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        requestHeader.add("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

        HttpEntity<ObjectNode> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(message, requestHeader);
        try {
            ResponseEntity<ObjectNode> responseFromSlack = restTemplate.exchange(
                    "https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage", HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, ObjectNode.class);
            log.info("[postMessageInChat], response: {}", responseFromSlack.getBody().asText());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("[postMessageInChat] ", e.getMessage());
        }
```

When I run this on my local machine it works fine but on deploying it to an environment, the bot replies non stop.

**Why is the bot replying continuously?**

Comment: I did not look at your code in detail, but could it be the same reason like in this case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59489908/slack-events-api-events-are-posted-multiple-times-for-responses-of-own-bot-us/59519428#59519428

Comment: makes sense, will try this. Thanks @ErikKalkoken